# BufferedWriter not writing to .txt file even after flushing the writer

Tags: java, android, writer

Here's the code I used, I get no errors or warnings but the file is empty, I created the aq.txt file and placed it in the workspace and it also shows in the project. I'm sure it's something stupid I'm missing but I just can't figure it out. Also, I tried all the other questions but the suggested answer is closing the stream and/or flushing it, both of which I do but they don't seem to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
     Writer writer = null;
 FileOutputStream fos= null;
 try{


     String xyz= "You should stop using xyz";
     writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
         new FileOutputStream(getFilesDir()+File.separator+"aq.txt")));
     writer.write(xyz);
     writer.flush();
 }    
 catch(IOException e) {
     System.out.println("Couldn't write to the file: " + e.toString());
 }
 finally{
     if(writer != null){
         try {
             writer.close();
         }
         catch(IOException e1) {
             e1.printStackTrace();
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: how are you reading the file?

Comment: You should print out the path after you calculated it. You may be surprised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
fos = openFileOutput(FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos));
writer.write(xyz);
writer.flush();
```

Context class provides a helper method [Context.openFileOutput(String name, int mode)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)  that will return a FileOutputStream to you for a file located in your applications Files directory.

I don't see any immediate reason why your way would not work, but I know I've used this other way successfully.

**EDIT:** After re-reading your question I think you are confused about where this file is going to be written to. It will not get written to the project folder inside of your workspace. This is going to be written to the internal storage of the android device that you run it on. Every application gets its own chunk of storage space located at `\data\data\[package-name]\Files\` Your file is going to get written to there so you won't be able to immediately open it up and see the contents of it (unless your device is rooted.) You will instead have to open it up with java code and print its contents to the Log or some other output method in order to verify that your write did/did not work.

**EDIT 2: Reading the file**

```
FileInputStream in = openFileInput(FILE_NAME);
InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(in);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
String line = br.readLine();
Log.d("TAG", line);
```

This will read and output to the log the first line of the file.

Comment: I'm sorry but it's just that I'm new to this; I'm running it on an avd on my laptop, can you specify how I can open it up with java code?

Comment: Thank you, I tried it now and it prints out what I'm trying to write in the file, but is there any way I can save it in the actual .txt file so that it appears when I open it?

Answer (score 0):

This will certainly work :

```
File file = new File("fileName");

FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);

BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);

writer.write("data to write in the file.");

writer.flush();
```